# Changing tick labels to percent

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, ticks

Suppose I have a graph with y values between 0 and 1 (say). How would I go about changing the tick labels to percentage (so that 0.1 would go to 10%, and so on)? Documentation seems silent on this point...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`PercentForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PercentForm.html) to express tick labels in percents:

```
ticks = {#, ToString[PercentForm[#]]} & /@ Range[0, 1, .1];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks }]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Quantity[x, "Percent"]` to get `x%`:

```
ticks2 = {#, ToString[Quantity[100 #, "Percent"], StandardForm]} & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/10];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks2}]
```

> same picture

**Update:** To label only major ticks:

```
tickF = Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][##] /.
  {a_, _NumberForm, b___} :> {a, ToString @ PercentForm[a], b} &;

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {Automatic,tickF}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that  makes more sense!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the option

```
Ticks -> {Automatic, Transpose@{Range[0., 1., 0.1], ToString[#] <> "%" & /@ Range[0, 100, 10]}}
```

For example

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Transpose@{Range[0., 1., 0.1], ToString[#] <> "%" & /@ Range[0, 100, 10]}}]
```

[image]

Or for a more general range of data we can use a function in `Ticks`

```
percentticks[ymin_, ymax_] := Transpose@{Range[ymin, ymax, (ymax - ymin)/10.], ToString[#] <> "%" & /@ Range[0, 100, 10]}

Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, percentticks}]
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly works, but not exactly transparent. Since Mathematica supports a bunch of number formats, one might thing %ages would be the first thing that came to mind (especially as there is AccountingForm). But noooo...