# Number formating in manipulate

Tags: manipulate, formatting

This is closely related to [this question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207964/changing-tick-labels-to-percent/207967#207967). Suppose I have a slider control for `Manipulate`. Can I display the slider label in percent (or, in general, any other formatted way)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Manipulate[x, 
 Row[{Control[{x, 0, 1}], Dynamic @ PercentForm[x]}, Spacer[5]]]
```

[image]

Comment: So, if I have a number of sliders, do I have a list of rows?

Comment: @Igor, yes. You can also use `Grid`; e.g.,`Grid[{{Control[{x, 0, 1}], Dynamic @ PercentForm[x]},{Control[{y, 0, 1}], Dynamic @ PercentForm[y]}}]`.

Comment: @Igor, re "do I have a _list_ of rows", you can have a _sequence_ of `Row`s. For example, `Manipulate[{x,y}, Row[{Control[{x, 0, 1}],Dynamic@PercentForm[x] }, Spacer[5]],Row[{Control[{y, 0, 1}],Dynamic@PercentForm[y] }, Spacer[5]]]`

Comment: Ah, OK, even better!

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a way to this using the default `Appearance->"Labeled"` method. But you can do it (and this is what I do) by using `Manipulator`.

So instead of writing

```
Manipulate[x,
  {{x,0,"x"},0,10,1,Appearance->"Labeled"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You would write

```
Manipulate[x,
 Grid[{{"x", 
    Manipulator[Dynamic[x, {x = #} &], {0, 10, 1}, 
     ImageSize -> Medium], Row[{Dynamic[x/10*100], "% km"}] (*anything you want*)
    }}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]