# Why the PercentForm for the y-axis Ticks in Plot function cannot work when specify Frame->True?

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

I am trying to plot the y-axis value as a percent form. By using `PercentForm` for the `Ticks` which I followed [Changing tick labels to percent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207964/changing-tick-labels-to-percent), I can plot the y-axis in percent. However, this approach only works when I do not specify the "Frame->True". Can anybody explain this to me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the option [`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) instead of `Ticks`:

```
ticks = {#, ToString[PercentForm[#]]} & /@ Range[0, 1, .1];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively, modify the labels of automatically-generated major ticks:

```
tickF = Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][##] /.
  {a_, _NumberForm, b___} :> {a, ToString @ PercentForm[a], b} &;

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickF, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helps a lot